# Spring-Google OAuth2 for stand alone applications

Tags: spring, google-signin, google-openid

I have a JavaFX client application, where it can log in to the service using Google OpenID.

- Client user clicks on Google Sign In
- Following URL will be opened in the default browser

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 response_type=code&
 client_id=
 scope=email&
 redirect_uri=localhost:8080/login/oauth2
 state=qwerrffadfadf
```

- User logs in to Google & Authorize
- Page will be auto redirected to `localhost:8080/login/oauth2` with auth code
- Server exchange auth code to access token
- Server validate and get user's email address

Now, when JavaFX client sends a request, the server should allow any resources to the authenticated user. But, as you can see, there is no way to connect Google users to the JavaFX client session. I have seen applications are using similar methods to allow social login (Postman, Nvidia Experience).

How should I handle this?

```
                           +------------------------+
                 +---------+  Authorization Code    +------------+
                 |         |        To              |            |
                 |   + ----+  Access token exchange +--------+   |
                 |   |     +------------------------+        |   |
                 |   |                                       |   |
                 |   |                                       |   |
                 |   |                                       |   |
                 |   |                                       |   |
                 |   |                                       |   |
                 |   |                                       |   |
                 |   |                                       |   |
                 |   v                                       |   |
             +---+---+----+                         +--------+---v------+
             |            |     Authorization       |                   |
             |  MyServer  +<-------+Code-+          |  Google Resource  |
             |            |              |          |       Server      |
             +------------+              |          |                   |
                                         |          +----+---------+----+
                                         |               |         ^
+-------------------------------------+  |               |         |
|                                     |  |               |         |
|                                     |  |               |         |
|         +-----------------+         |  |               |         |
|         |                 |         |  |               |         |
|         |  JavaFX Client  |         |  |               |         |
|         |                 |         |  |         Authorization   |
|         +-------+---------+         |  |             Code        | Authorization
|                 |                   |  |               |         | Request
|                 +                   |  |               |         |
|     Clicked on Google Sign in       |  |               |         |
|                 |                   |  |               |         |
|                 v                   |  |               |         |
|          +------+-------+           |  |               |         |
|          |              +--------------+               |         |
|          |              |           |                  |         |
|          |  Client Web  +<-----------------------------+         |
|          |    Browser   |           |                            |
|          |              +----------------------------------------+
|          +--------------+           |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|          Client's Computer          |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```